# Numerically Calculating an Integral in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to numerically calculate an integral in C++ using the extended trapezoidal method. The equation I am trying to integrate is (ln(x))^2 using 200 Simpson's points. But, it approaches infinity as x approaches 0, so when I try to find the value of (ln(0))^2 it returns "inf". How do I most accurately estimate the area between the lowerBound (0) and the first Simpson's point (1/200)?

I have tried setting the lowerBound to the minimum value of a double and it ruins the approximation by including too much extra area above the curve.

```
/* Sum f2 ... fx */
for (int i = 1; i < points; i++) {
    u = ((upperBound - lowerBound) / points) * i;
    sum += (log(u) * log(u));
}

/*Returns area under curve*/
return ((upperBound - lowerBound) * sum / points);
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that method can be used for functions that aren't bounded?

Comment: My understanding is that the integral does not converge, i.e. the exact result is infinite.

Comment: For a definite integral starting from a limit approaching zero it is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods of quadrature which can be applied to open intervals (to avoid the poles), like
 [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) or the [Newton-Coates formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas).

If you can use only Simpson, you still have a couple of option:

- Chose the points in a smaller interval. Once you have fixed a step *h*, start sampling at 0 + *h*/2 and go up to upper limit - *h*/2.
- Use a different approch for the first subinterval, like a modified trapezoidal rule with sample points at h/2, h/4, h/8, ... until convergence or just a fixed number of samples.